# Phantom 4 live stream to RTMP server using DJI SDK

Tags: rtmp, dji-sdk

The DJI Go app was recently updated so that it could stream live video to an RTMP server. Is it possible to implement live video streaming to an RTMP server in a custom app built on the DJI Mobile SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain H.264 stream from SDK/Video Previewer project and then use transcoders (like [X.264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html). Please pay attention to licence and royalty requirements when using for commercial purposes).

Checkout the below iOS and Android Sample Projects:

https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/iOS-FPVDemo

https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/sample-code/index.html

Comment: Do you know of any Swift libraries that contain functions taking the H.264 video stream as an argument that can broadcast the stream to a RTMP server?